# How to check if form was submitted

Tags: php, html, forms

My question is how to check which form was submitted if I have 2 different forms with the same name, and I can't change the name.

For example I have 2 forms and 2 php scripts that evaluate them:

```html
<form action=mypage.php method=post>
  <input type=text name=name>
  <input type=submit name=ok value=ok>
</form>
```

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['ok'])) {
    $name=$_POST['name'];
  }
?>
```

```html
<form action=mypage.php method=post>
  <input type=text name=pass>
  <input type=submit name=ok value=ok>
</form>
```

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['ok'])) { // <- here is wrong
    $pass=$_POST['pass]']; // this code is not executing
  }
?>
```

How I can differentiate these two submits without changing their names?

P.S I can't bring the (Forms) together.

Comment: Enjoy ?? wooot  ...

Comment: you can help)? please.

Comment: @DanPlaton You say "here is wrong" in the example, but what goes wrong exactly? Do you get an error? The variable isn't set? Etc?

Comment: @MrLister question edited so , there where the word Enjoy in this last , so what we're supposed to enjoy ? that's why I commented his Question

Comment: @MrLister this line not executing) sorry) yes and a var isn't set.

Comment: @DanPlaton From the question it isn't too clear, but you have two forms in two different pages (one form ion each), right? that both submit to the same php file? Also, "this line not executing" is ambiguous; do you mean code execution never reaches there, or that the result is false?

Comment: Change the values. Each `<input type=submit name=ok value=ok>` can have a different value.

Comment: @DanPlaton its good to add a hidden field which can help you determine what page the form comes from.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One solution is to add a hidden input on both forms:

```
<input type="hidden" name="form1" value="name" />
```

and:

```
<input type="hidden" name="form2" value="pass" />
```

Then to check which one has been submitted:

```
if(isset($_POST['ok']) && isset($_POST['form1'])){

// For the first form

}
```

And:

```
if(isset($_POST['ok']) && isset($_POST['form2'])){

// For the second form

}
```